# accessing pointed value with pointer without *

Tags: c, pointers

I am reading Head First C book and in pointers chapter(and pointer arithmetic) i couldnt understand something.

I have to write arrays like this to print its 3rd element:

```
main(){
int drinks[] = {4, 2, 3};
printf("3rd order: %i drinks\n", *(drinks + 2));
}
```

But when using pointer i need to write like this

```
void skip(char*);
int main() {
    char *msg_from_amy="dont call me";
    skip(msg_from_amy);
}

void skip(char *msg){
    puts(msg+6);
}
```

Shouldnt i need to write *(msg+6) to access 7th element? msg holds an address and msg+6 means ahead of 6 bytes from begining. so it is still an address, i need to write *(msg+6) to access stored value in that address from my perspective but it doesnt work. But why quoted one right answer, why i cant figure out.

Edit: Actually i asked wrongly my question. And edited code snippets. Here is output of:

```
puts(msg+6);
printf("%c\n", *(msg+6));
printf("%s\n", *(msg+6));
```

```
all me
a
```

I expected get "all me" output from 2nd printf like 1st one. But i think i understand the reason. its difference of puts and printf argument list. Thx for answers.

Btw why 3rd printf prints just a blank character?

Comment: `puts` accepts a pointer, not a single `char` element, as argument

Comment: BTW: you're using `skip` without declaring it. Either declare `void skip(char *msg);`  before `main`, or put the whole `skip` function before `main`.

Comment: also note that `"%c"` is the wrong format specifier for `int`, use `"%d"` instead: `printf("3rd order: %d drinks\n", *(drinks + 2));`. Furthermore, the more common practice is to use bracket notation when accessing an element of an array, eg `drinks[2]`, but this is identical functionality to what you're doing with `*(drinks + 2)`

Comment: BTW: what output do you expect? And what output do you get?

Comment: MAn thank for fast answer. But i get same result with printf("%s\n", msg+6); printf("%s\n", *(msg+6)); gives error.

Comment: `*(msg + 6)` is a single character, converted to `int` by the default promotion rules for variadic functions (functions like `printf()`).  `%s` expects a pointer, not a character or integer.

Comment: @hepl __what__ result do you get? `printf("%s\n", *(msg+6));` cannot work, because `%s` expects a pointer to char, but `*(msg+6)` is a single `char`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky actually i have declaration upper of the main. i expected to access 7th element with writing *(msg+6) but it gives error core dumped or something like that.

Comment: @yano Well `"%c"` does expect an `int`, but it does seem obvious that OP intended the number to be printed rather than an unprintable character!

Comment: `msg+6` is a memory address. `*(msg+6)` is the content at that address. It really isn't more complicated than that.

Comment: @hepl the code you show is fine, it shouldn't result in a core dump.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to write arrays like this to print its 3rd element:
>
> ```
> main(){
> int drinks[] = {4, 2, 3};
> printf("3rd order: %i drinks\n", *(drinks + 2));
> }
> ```

No, you don't have to do that, and it is very non-idiomatic.  Most people would use

```
printf("3rd order: %i drinks\n", drinks[2]);
```

Moving on ...

> ```
> void skip(char *msg){
>     puts(msg+6);
> }
> ```
>
> Shouldnt i need to write *(msg+6) to access 7th element?

Yes, `*(msg+6)` to access 7th element or, better, `msg[6]`.  But you're not trying to access the 7<sup>th</sup> element.  You are providing to `puts` the *substring* that *starts* at the 7<sup>th</sup> element.  `msg+6` is just fine for that.

> Here is output of:
>
> ```
> puts(msg+6);
> printf("%c\n", *(msg+6));
> printf("%s\n", *(msg+6));
> ```

> ```
> all me
> a
> ```
>
> I expected get "all me" output from 2nd printf like 1st one

I don't see why.  The `%c` formatting directive converts and prints *one  character*, which is good because that's what you pass as the corresponding argument.  It's not about a difference between `puts` and `printf`.  Rather, it's mostly about the deep difference between `msg+6` and `*(msg+6)`.

> Btw why 3rd printf prints just a blank character?

No one can say.  The behavior of your third `printf` call is undefined because the formatting directive `%s`, which expects a `char *` argument, is not correctly type matched with the corresponding argument `*(msg+6)`, which is a `char`.  Anything could happen.  And this underscores my previous point: there is no deep difference in this regard between `puts` and `printf`.  You appear to want:

```
printf("%s\n", msg+6);
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, lest someone else make the same misinterpretation, I have made a small edit to clarify what that "yes" was meant to refer to.

Answer (score 0):

> I expected get "all me" output from 2nd printf like 1st one.

The `%c` specifier is intended to print exactly one character. Furthermore, it's impossible to go to `msg+7` from `*(msg+6)`.

> Btw why 3rd printf prints just a blank character?

Because `%s` expects a pointer. `*(msg+6)` is not a pointer.

You should compile with `-Wall -Wextra`. That will make the compiler warn you about a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value that `msg` points to, you need to deference it using the `*` operator. So, if you want to get the sixth element pointed by `msg`, you need to advance by 6 and then deference it. The problem with `printf("%s\n", *(msg+6));` is that `%s` expects a string, but `*(msg+6)` is a character. You can try to change `%s` with `%c`.

Remember that a string in c is a collection of characters ended by the null character '\0'.